# How to target multiple / variable IDs when calling FancyBox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have multiple posts being looped on a page and being given IDs of #content1, #content2, #content3 etc.

How do I change my jQuery to recognise all of the multiple IDs? (There could be any number of them).

So: `$('a[href="#content"]').fancybox({`

needs to be like: `$('a[href="#content1"]', 'a[href="#content2"]', 'a[href="#content3"]').fancybox({`

But without listing them all individually.

Here is the code that is creating the numbers at the end of #content:

```
    <?php $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'otherwork',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'=>'date',
        'order'=>'ASC'
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); $i = 0; ?>

        <article>
            <ul class="otherwork">
             <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $i++; ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="#content<?php echo $i; ?>" ><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'otherwork-thumb' ); ?></a>
                    <div id="content<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display:none">
                        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </article>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `$('a[href="#content1"], a[href="#content2"], a[href="#content3"]').fancybox({` pass comma separated selectors. However I would suggest you to a common class

Comment: Is there not way to catch all possible numbers? There will be lots more than 3! I cant use a common class as the content will only load the first instance of the inline content.

Comment: Then you can go for Jay Blanchard answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "begins with" attribute selector -

```
$('a[href^=#content"]')
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: Boom! Thanks so much Jay!

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$('a[href*="#content"]').fancybox({});//For href containing `#content`
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the "starts with" selector in jQuery:

```
$('a[href^="#content"]').fancyBox({ ... });
```

This will select all anchors with a `href` that starts with `#content`